# How to manage a lot of SSH connection information of EC2 instances from ubuntu using different .pem files

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I have to access a lot of AWS EC2 instances from my local machine regularly. Their IP addresses are not mapped to any domain to I need to login to them using command like :

```
ssh -i keyfile.pem ec2-user@<ip address of the instance>
```

There are over 10 EC2 instances and some have same key file some have different. The problem is that I do not remember their IP addresses and each time I have to look them up on my AWS console and then copy paste their IP address. Is there any way I can make this process a lot faster by storing some aliases to these instances locally and access them using some GUI tool ? I don't want to use PUTTY since I like the Ubuntu shell.

Comment: You can create alias  _alias  MyInstanceID="ssh -i /path/to/Key/File ubuntu@Ip-address"_

Comment: you can use my script to list your instance with their ip and tags at the command line shell ... `http://linuxhomepage.com/free/list-aws.py`

Comment: you can associate any ip with any name you like by appending to the file `/etc/hosts`.  this is even more useful if/when you start using ipv6 with those long addresses.

Comment: you should have *exactly one* ssh key (referred to as *id*) per user. so for youself, just have one key pair.  if you have multiple users, then who launches an instance should append the other public keys to `.ssh/authorized_keys`.  a team can share them all as one file, concatenated ... each keeping their private halves to themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with shortcuts by specify the hostname, username, port, and the private key. Please refer the [official docs](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config&sec=5).

```
Host MyInstance1
Host example.com or ipaddress
User ubuntu
IdentityFile /path/to/privatekey/MyInstance1.pem
```

Permission:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Then Try to access by

```
ssh  MyInstance1
```

You can also try with aliases :

File:

```
vi vim ~/.bash_aliases
```

Then

```
alias MyInstance1='ssh ubuntu@ec2.amazon.com -i /path/to/private-key/MyInstance1.pem'
```

Answer (score 1):

An SSH config is great for this, however, upon redeploying new instances the IPs will change and your ssh config will become stale. I wrote a tool that will pull the latest EC2 inventory from AWS and ssh into the system that matches your search: https://github.com/wagoodman/bridgy

```
bridgy ssh <some-instance-id>
```

Or if you add a tag called `Name` to each instance then you can use that too:

```
bridgy ssh <some-name-tag-value>
```

If you have the `~/.aws` creds/config defined as you would with the `aws-cli` as well as the following in `~/.bridgy/config.yml`:

```
inventory:
    source: aws
    update_at_start: true
ssh:
    user: <your ssh user>
...
```

Then it should work!

One last thing: If you add all of your SSH keys to an `ssh-agent` then that will solve your problem regarding multiple key files (all keys are tried against the host you attempt to log into).